# What is the difference between Windows Server 2008 Enterprise and Standard edition?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'd just want to know what is the major difference between Windows Server 2008 Enterprise Edition and the Standard Edition regarding support, functionality etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Microsoft have been kind enough to have a whole page dedicated to your question ([Clicky](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-editions-overview.aspx)), and only a few clicks away from their landing page too!

- ["Updated" link (to a pdf)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/C/6/FC6006B5-866E-42C1-88F8-9AC4B8BC610D/WS%20Brand%20Pages%20-%20Editions%20Comparison%20Guide.pdf).
- ["Updated" link (using Internet Archive Wayback machine)](http://web.archive.org/web/20101110004336/http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-editions-overview.aspx)

Comment: Now in 2012 that link provides no useful information regarding Windows Server 2008!

Comment: @amyassin And besides, the proper thing to do with a broken link is to edit the post and update the link.

Answer (score 4):

Windows Server 2008 Enterprise Edition adds these features compared to the Standard edition:

- Active Directory Certificate Services are not limited to creating Certificate Authorities – no other ADCS features (NDES, Online Responder Service).
- Active Directory Federation Services
- File Services are not limited to 1 standalone DFS root.
- Network Policy and Access Services are not limited to 250 RRAS connections, 50 IAS connections and 2 IAS Server Groups.
- Remote Desktop Services are not limited to 250 Remote Desktop Services Gateway connections.

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-compare-roles.aspx) you can find a nice comparison by role table.